# Code analysis in ASP.NET web application

Tags: analysis

I am using VS 2010; all these days I am confortable runnig code analysis on class libraries.

But for a web application, the UI control names with prefixes like ddl, pnl, etc are causing code analysis warnings as "Correct the spelling...". I googled and think this can be addressed using rulesets; but didn't find a way to suppress these..any pointers ?

Comment: Hungarian notation is frowned upon.  Don't use those prefixes.

Comment: Control names are a weird case. People who frown upon hungarian notation otherwise (including me!) still tend to use that for UI control names at times. Wonder what's up with that?

Comment: Just looking for a common solution. Code analysis report, CustomDictionary, Code coverage, etc all these are client deliverables..so curious to see a common solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could add them to a custom dictionary.

Comment: Thats the last option. I am looking for a solution, which can be implmented across other team too. Of course, I can copy the list of prefixes from CustomDictionary into other team's specific developement.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using those prefixes?

The most common reason I've seen people give for this is "Hungarian Notation."  However, as I've tried to point out in a number of jobs over the years, "you're doing it wrong."  Within an IDE like VS 2010, is there any real reason to prefix every `DropDownList` instance with "ddl"?  Both you and the IDE know it's a `DropDownList`.  There's no question or confusion about that.

The idea behind Hungarian Notation isn't to "prefix every variable with a shorthand of its class" but rather to "prefix every variable with what it is."  What something is doesn't have to mean its class or type, it's more an idea of what that object intuitively represents.  Sure, it's a `DropDownList`.  But what does that `DropDownList` mean?  Is it part of a particular grouping of elements in the UI?  That grouping's designation would provide a lot more information than "ddl" ever would.

As an example, say I have an application with various connection strings.  In a given method in my DAL, I store one of them in a variable called `strConnection`.  Well, that's adhering to the notation, but it's not telling me anything important.  I know it's a string.  (I can see its declaration, I can mouse over it in the IDE, etc.)  And I know it's a connection string based on its usage.  But which one is it?  What part of the business does it serve?  If instead it was called `connstringHR` then I could immediately infer that it's the connection string for the HR database.